# How to distribute data with Android app, but reduce the ease of it being copied?

Tags: android

If I build and distribute an Android app with a mysql database, it's pretty straightforward for someone to copy the database, and use it as a basis for their own app, on Android or elsewhere.

I see my options as:

Store data in the cloud instead, downloaded as needed

Accept it'll get ripped off, take the risk, focus on making my app great

Obfuscate the data (perhaps on a char-by-char basis so I can move in either direction, as I need to perform searches on my dataset)

Are there any better ways?

Comment: It's primarily dates, ints, and text (up to 32k), so size-wise not that large. Row-count in the range 5,000-100,000. No images/video or large binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encrypt the data and obtain a decryption key from the cloud (presumably after some sort of authentication) the first time the app runs.